# Generate permutations of values in fixed intervals

Tags: python

Suppose I have a possible values like the following:

```
vals = [0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 0.98]
```

Now, I want to generate list of len 5.. but based on every possible combinations..

```
perm_values = [0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85],
              [0.85, 0.90, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85],
              [0.85, 0.85, 0.90, 0.85, 0.85],
                ...
               [0.98, 0.98, 0.98, 0.98, 0.98]]
```

I am pretty sure, there is a pythonic way to do this..
I am currently, having like 5 loops indexing to vals array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simply

```
from itertools import product

vals = [0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 0.98]
perm_vals = list(product(vals, repeat=5))
```